# I need to write a Maple procedure that finds every solution to the following inequalities:

Tags: maple

I have the two inequalities

y<=-1/2 * x  and y>= -2/5 * x, subject to the constraint -20 <= x <= 0.

Does anyone have an idea how I'd get maple to display (or better yet, count) all the solutions to these inequalities?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! Good I'm getting some people looking at this, friendly as they may be.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many real-valued solutions in the feasible region. So perhaps you meant to specify that you want only the integer-valued feasible points.

```
restart:
interface(warnlevel=0):

ineqs := { y<=-1/2*x, y>=-2/5*x }:

feasP := plots:-inequal (ineqs, x=-20..0, y=0..10, nolines ):

isols := { seq( seq({x=i} union s, s in {isolve( eval(ineqs,x=i) )}),
                i=-20..0 ) };

  {{x = -20, y = 8}, {x = -20, y = 9}, {x = -20, y = 10}, 
   {x = -19, y = 8}, {x = -19, y = 9}, {x = -18, y = 8},
   {x = -18, y = 9}, {x = -17, y = 7}, {x = -17, y = 8},
   {x = -16, y = 7}, {x = -16, y = 8}, {x = -15, y = 6},
   {x = -15, y = 7}, {x = -14, y = 6}, {x = -14, y = 7}, 
   {x = -13, y = 6}, {x = -12, y = 5}, {x = -12, y = 6},
   {x = -11, y = 5}, {x = -10, y = 4}, {x = -10, y = 5},
   {x = -9, y = 4}, {x = -8, y = 4}, {x = -7, y = 3},
   {x = -6, y = 3}, {x = -5, y = 2}, {x = -4, y = 2}, 
   {x = -2, y = 1}, {x = 0, y = 0}}

nops(isols);
                                 29

ptsP := plots:-pointplot( [ seq( eval([x,y],s), s in isols ) ],
                          color=red, symbol=solidcircle ):

plots:-display( feasP, ptsP );
```

[image]

If this is homework then it's possible that the instructor intended you to iterate over integer y values (instead of calling `isolve`, say).

```
isols := { seq( seq({x=i,y=j}, j=ceil(-2/5*i)..-1/2*i), i=-20..0 ) };
```

Comment: If this is homework then it's possible that the intention of the instructor is that you use iterate over the possible y-values (using the lower and upper inequalities for y) for each instantiated integer x value. You could do that using a pair of nested for..do loops or a pair of nested `seq` calls.

Comment: This is more of something I need to give a final answer to a question I already solved. I got 29, but making an algorithm for it is what's baffling me.

Comment: I see. I edited the Answer and gave a solution using a pair of `seq` calls.